# File Management and sync by proxy, via file catalog?

Tags: hard-drive, script, sync, file-management

I want to organize files/folders of my external hard drives when the drives are offline, and then sync the changes manually when I plugin a hard drive.

**Situation:**
I have lots of files to organize, on large external HDDs. It can only be done manually, and will take days/weeks at a time. Being actively connected to that drive, will mean lots of drive spinning and a waste of drive life-span each time.

**The idea:**
I'm imagining a mashup of two concepts - file catalog and action queue.

[WinCatalog - Explorer-like UI showing DVD/HDD contents offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dix3u.jpg)      |
[Easeus - Partition tool with queued/pending actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1FLk.jpg)

First, remember a program like [WinCatalog](https://www.wincatalog.com/sshotes/en-w3-main-wnd-1024.png)? They catalog your CD/DVD/HDD folder structure in full. Thus making it easy to browse or search your data, even if that particular drive is offline (or not inserted) at the moment.
Second, think of disk partitioning tools like Easeus. They let you queue up many actions ("pending operations"), so you can visually see the result. You can undo/redo with no actual changes made to the partition table. When happy you can "apply" your actions, to be carried out in sequence.

My imaginary perfect offline file managing tool would let me:

1. Catalog/index full contents of any HDD (internal/external).
2. Have an explorer-like GUI, for drag-drop/rename/delete file operations.
3. Be stable over many weeks of adding such incremental actions.
4. Eventually I'd connect external drives one by one. I would open the tool, and click a button to apply the pending file operations.

**What I've tried:**
Manual sync using tools like Beyond Compare. But that can't do what I am imagining. Because it can only compare+sync from an existing/online filesystem to another existing/online filesystem. And that'd mean keeping some *OTHER* HDD drive connected, and spinning its darned rusty life away! Also, this data can't be organized while sitting on a NAS for the same reason.

**Summary:**
*I need to organize a drive's data, using an index/catalog at leisure when the drive is offline. And then apply changes at will when I connect the external HDD.*
Perhaps there already are tools that do what I described? Perhaps some tool goes part of the way, which still helps me a lot? Perhaps a customizable GUI app that records actions in the index/catalog, and generates file-moving CMD scripts?

FWIW, I consider myself a power-user on Windows, but I'm unable to program such a tool myself. I can learn from scripts and modify them for my purpose, or use multiple GUI apps in sequence to do what I'm looking for.